# How to create table from a query with a case clause column in DB2?

Tags: database, db2

Hello I am trying to create a table from a query like this: (sort of)

```
    create table afiexdb.afiext as(
select a.afiaux, a.aficod, a.aficta, a.afidep, b.mb_nom_reg as AFIDEPDSC, a.afimun, d.mb_nom_ciu as AFIMUNDSC, a.afidirchk, a.afifching, a.afidptnac, c.mb_nom_reg as DPTNACDSC, a.afimunnac, e.mb_nom_ciu as MUNNACDSC, 
                 cast(CASE WHEN a.afiestciv = 'S' THEN 'SOLTERO'
                 WHEN a.afiestciv = 'C' THEN 'CASADO'
                 WHEN a.afiestciv = 'D' THEN 'DIVORCIADO'
                 WHEN a.afiestciv = 'V' THEN 'VIUDO'
                 WHEN a.afiestciv = 'U' THEN 'UNION LIBRE'
                 END as char(11)) as AFIESTCIV,
a.afifchmue, a.afifchnac, a.afifchprm, a.afifchret, a.afihom, a.afinro, a.afiprof, a.afiserie, a.afisexo, a.afiults, rtrim(a.cli1ernomb)||' '||rtrim(a.cli2donomb)||' '||rtrim(a.cli1erapel)||' '|| rtrim(a.cli2doapel) as AFINOMBRE, 
rtrim(a.clidirec1)||' '||rtrim(a.clidirec2)||' '||rtrim(a.clidirec3) as AFIDIR, a.cliidentid, f.afitel1, f.afitel2, f.afitel3, 
a.estcod, g.estdsc, h.gracod, h.gradsc, a.grucod, i.grudsc, a.unicod, j.unidsc, 
m.pplcod as PAGCOD, m.ppldsc as PAGDSC, afiedad(a.aficod, a.afihom, cast ('20170405' as char(8))) as EDADAFI, 
ifnull(n.pricot,0) as PRICOT, ifnull(n.ultcot,0) as ULTCOT, n.totcot as TOTCOT, n.anioscot, cast(null as decimal) as RESLAB
from afiliadbf.afiliado a
left join lisamb30db.regdep b on b.mb_region = a.afidep
left join lisamb30db.regdep c on c.mb_region = a.afidptnac
left join lisamb30db.region d on a.afidep = d.mb_region and a.afimun = d.mb_ciudad
left join lisamb30db.region e on a.afidptnac = e.mb_region and a.afimunnac = e.mb_ciudad
left join afiliadbf.afiadinf f on a.aficod = f.aficod and a.afihom = f.afihom
left join afiliadbf.estado g on a.estcod = g.estcod
left join afiliadbf.grado h on a.gracod = h.gracod
left join afiliadbf.grupo i on a.grucod = i.grucod
left join afiliadbf.unidad j on a.unicod = j.unicod
left join prsipmdb2.pagunida l on a.unicod = l.pagunidad
left join afiliadbf.platip m on l.pagcod = m.pplcod
left join (select a.aficod, a.afihom, MIN(rtrim(a.cotanio)||'-'||case when a.cotmes<10 then '0'||a.cotmes else rtrim(a.cotmes)end cotaniomes) as pricot, 
              MAX(rtrim(a.cotanio)||'-'||case when a.cotmes<10 then '0'||a.cotmes else rtrim(a.cotmes) end cotaniomes) as ultcot, sum(a.cotmon) as totcot, 
                  cast(count(a.cotanio)/12 as char(2))||' Años '||cast(count(a.cotanio)-(count(a.cotanio)/12)*12 as char(2))||' meses' as  anioscot
           from afiliadbf.cotiza a
           group by a.aficod, a.afihom) n on n.aficod = a.aficod and n.afihom = a.afihom
) with no data
```

I get invalid symbol when I include the case clause column. I know DB2 is strong typed so that is why I casted each result value as varchar I also tried to cast the entire case clause [cast(case()end as char(10)], and definitely can not have a 'cast as' somewhere if not some error will pop up for sure.

Any advice on how to create this column based on the case clause column?

Comment: A query usually has a `SELECT` somewhere in it.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include either your actual query or a real example query that demonstrates the problem, as well as some information about your data. Also, the exact error message please.  If all the results of the case statements are strings, as in the example you gave, then this error would not occur, regardless of whether you cast everything.

Comment: I updated and placed the entire query. The select part when ran works perfect it returns the rows it is supossed to return.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your case like this (you have forget 'ELSE' into your case) :

```
CASE 
WHEN a.afiestciv = 'S' THEN 'SOLTERO'
WHEN a.afiestciv = 'C' THEN 'CASADO'
WHEN a.afiestciv = 'D' THEN 'DIVORCIADO'
WHEN a.afiestciv = 'V' THEN 'VIUDO'
WHEN a.afiestciv = 'U' THEN 'UNION LIBRE'
ELSE cast(null as char(11))
END as AFIESTCIV
```